# Telephony Bot Using botframework in nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework, azure-communication-services

I'm trying to build a Telephony bot using ACS and bot framework in node js but it's not working.

here is how I'm sending back the response.

```
let speech = `<speak
                version="1.0"
                xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
                xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts"
                xml:lang="en-US">
                <voice name="en-US-JessaNeural">
                  <mstts:express-as type="cheerful">That'd be just amazing!</mstts:express-as>
                </voice>
                <voice name="ja-JP-Ayumi-Apollo">
                  <prosody pitch="+150%">素晴らしい!</prosody>
                </voice>
              </speak>`
        session.send(speech);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telephony channel which is currently in preview, and as such, comes with preview terms.
Here are the details and samples about the Telephony: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-IVR.